# How can I specify a Poller for a queue channel using java-dsl?

Tags: spring-integration

I want to consume messages from a Queue channel using `java-dsl`, but `Integrations.from` doesn't have a signature allowing me to specify a Poller.

How can I achieve this?

Ex.:

```
 @Bean
 IntegrationFlow flow() {
   return IntegrationFlows.from(this.channel())
                      .handle(...)
                      .get();
 }

 @Bean
 MessageChannel channel() {
     return MessageChannels.queue().get();
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, actually it is an endpoint responsibility to provide poller properties.

If you are familiar with an XML configuration you should remember that to poll from `<queue>` we should configure `<poller>` sub-element for `<service-activator>` etc.

The same approach is applied in Java DSL as well. The next endpoint definition should be with desired `poller`:

```
IntegrationFlows.from(this.channel())
                  .handle(..., e -> e.poller(Pollers...))
                  .get();
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with XML (I came from camel).  I have tried here. Works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've had trouble for some reason setting a poller on the endpoint definition as Artem described - for some reason it gets ignored. You can always set a default poller. This has worked for me:

```
@Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
public PollerMetadata poller() {
    return Pollers.fixedRate(500).get();
}
```